Is there a way to prevent the ".." folder in Java?
I am making a program which allows the user to control a certain folder and I ran into a security issue which allows the user to read files "../YouShouldNotBeAbleToReadThisFile.txt" and I was wondering if there is a way to block this behavior without manually running filenames through a filter to avoid a slip-up.
I tried to look for a possible method to do this in the FileSystem object and the Files class but I did not find anything.

The .. just refers to the parent directory. If you do not want the user to read it then you need to check each path that they try to access.

Probably want Path#normalize and Path#toAbsolutePath and compare against approved locations.

I know how to manually "sanitize" the file path, I just want to know if there is a way to make Java (or the operating system) sanitize the filepath automatically so I can't slip up and forget to sanitize a filepath.

You're trying to fix this at the wrong level. If that's happening in your app, then your security has failed in the OS

In other words, your application should probably be running as a certain user that only has access to authorized folders.

Maybe Path.startsWith

or a combination: userPath.toAbsolutePath().normalize().startsWith(approvedPath) (assuming approvedPath is already absolute and normalized)
